# Unable to start WiFi hotspot in HP laptop

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, wireless-hotspot

I am unable to start the wifi hotspot. Seems that the hostednetwork is not supported.

The following information is shown when I typed "netsh wlan show driver" in command prompt:

```
Driver                    : Realtek RTL8723BE 802.11 bgn Wi-Fi Adapter
Vendor                    : Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Provider                  : Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Date                      : 17-08-2017
Version                   : 2023.58.731.2017
INF file                  : oem38.inf
Type                      : Native Wi-Fi Driver
Radio types supported     : 802.11n 802.11g 802.11b
FIPS 140-2 mode supported : Yes
802.11w Management Frame Protection supported : Yes
Hosted network supported  : No
Authentication and cipher supported in infrastructure mode:
                            Open            None
                            WPA2-Personal   CCMP
                            Open            WEP-40bit
                            Open            WEP-104bit
                            Open            WEP
                            WPA-Enterprise  TKIP
                            WPA-Personal    TKIP
                            WPA2-Enterprise TKIP
                            WPA2-Personal   TKIP
                            WPA-Enterprise  CCMP
                            WPA-Personal    CCMP
                            WPA2-Enterprise CCMP
                            Vendor defined  TKIP
                            Vendor defined  CCMP
                            Vendor defined  Vendor defined
                            Vendor defined  Vendor defined
                            WPA2-Enterprise Vendor defined
                            WPA2-Enterprise Vendor defined
                            Vendor defined  Vendor defined
                            Vendor defined  Vendor defined
IHV service present       : Yes
IHV adapter OUI           : [00 e0 4c], type: [00]
IHV extensibility DLL path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\Rtlihvs.dll
IHV UI extensibility ClSID: {6c2a8cca-b2a2-4d81-a3b2-4e15f445c312}
IHV diagnostics CLSID     : {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
Wireless Display Supported: Yes (Graphics Driver: Yes, Wi-Fi Driver: Yes)
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

According to your information, your computer doesn't support hosted network:

> Hosted network supported  : No

This feature is required to enable wifi hotspot.

Comment: It was hosting WiFi a month ago... Maybe after some updates it is not working... Please help me get the hosted network supported as YES

Comment: Please check the manufacturer's website and see if there is the latest updates for the wireless network driver, if so, install it.